# Inversion on an internal groupoid

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with pullbacks, with $\mathscr{G}=({\bf Ob}_\mathscr{G},{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G},cod,dom,{\bf 1}, \circ_{\mathscr{G}},-^{-1})$ an [internal groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category#internal_groupoid) in $\mathcal{C}$. I'm trying to see that $-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}=1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}}$, and the best I've got so far is the following somewhat ugly series of identities:

$$1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}}=p_0\circ\langle1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}},dom\rangle=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ(1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}}\times_{{\bf Ob}_\mathscr{C}}{\bf 1})\circ\langle1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}},dom\rangle$$

$$=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ(1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}}\times_{{\bf Ob}_\mathscr{C}}{\bf 1})\circ\langle1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}},dom\circ-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}\rangle=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}},{\bf 1}\circ dom\circ-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}\rangle$$

$$=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}},\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle-^{-1},1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}}\rangle\circ-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}\rangle=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}},-^{-1}\rangle,-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}\rangle$$ $$=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle{\bf 1}\circ cod,-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}\rangle=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle{\bf 1}\circ cod\circ-^{-1}\circ-^{-1},-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}\rangle$$

$$=\circ_\mathscr{G}\circ\langle{\bf 1}\circ cod,1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}}\rangle\circ-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}=1_{{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}}\circ-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}=-^{-1}\circ-^{-1}.$$

These were obtained by staring at the following simpler identities for a sufficiently long time:

$$f=f\circ1_{dom(f)}=f\circ(f^{-1}\circ(f^{-1})^{-1})=(f\circ f^{-1})\circ(f^{-1})^{-1}=1_{cod((f^{-1})^{-1})}\circ(f^{-1})^{-1}=(f^{-1})^{-1}.$$

I've begun the diagram chase to verify that this all shakes out, however this strikes me as a very cumbersome proof for something I'd think was simple and trivial to show -- the authors of the book I'm working through that mention this fact in passing seem to think so as well.

Is there a simpler proof that I've missed, perhaps obtained by Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C}$ and considering ${\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{G}):\mathcal{C}^{op}\to{\bf Set}$ or something along these lines?

Comment: Sure, an internal groupoid represents an ordinary groupoid under Yoneda, and certainly inversion is an involution for ordinary groupoids.

Comment: @KevinCarlson When you say that it represents an ordinary groupoid what exactly does that mean? There is a natural isomorphism between the representable presheaves at the object of objects and the object of arrows and some functors between regular groupoids? On further reflection this interpretation makes little sense, could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: No, if you hom into the entirety of the data of $\mathcal G$ from a fixed object then that gives you the objects, arrows, source, target functions etc in an ordinary small groupoid.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ah, much appreciated!